# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Truncate'. Must declare scalar variable '@table'

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I'm quite new to SQL and I'm not sure why the following code is producing the error in title:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Truncate (@table varchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    EXEC ('TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @table);
END
```

Comment: truncate is a key word just like drop, try using tbltruncate etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Truncate is a reserved word, you cannot use it in the procedure name unquoted. You can do this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[Truncate] (@table varchar(50)) 
AS BEGIN     
  SET NOCOUNT ON;     
  EXEC ('TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @table); 
END
```

But when you run it, you'll have to say

```
dbo.[Truncate] 'tablename'
```

Alternatively change the name of the procedure to TruncateTable:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TruncateTable (@table varchar(50)) 
AS BEGIN     
  SET NOCOUNT ON;     
  EXEC ('TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @table); 
END
```

then you can call it as

```
EXEC TruncateTable 'tablename'
```

Answer (score 3):

`TRUNCATE` is a keyword, so you should name your procedure something else, ex:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TruncateTable (@table varchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    EXEC ('TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @table);
END
```

Answer (score 3):

TRUNCATE is a reserved or keyword in SQL Server. Just change the name to something else. Avoid putting [ ] around it like [TRUNCATE]

Answer (score 1):

Use some other name for the procedure instead of `Truncate` e.g. use `trucateMyTable`

**Reason:**

`Truncate` is a key word and

A **variable/procedure/function name** can not be a keyword.